# Changing the value of a select on focus

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a select the first option is `Search by date`. I want to make it so that when the select gets focus this value changes (to `All dates`) as this option returns the data for all dates.
I have got as far as this;

```
$("#select-date").focus(function() {
    window.alert('Focus!');
    $('#select-date option[value="Search by Date"]').attr("value", "All Dates");
});
```

With the alert as a test which triggers fine `I have found my select`, the 2nd does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us your current HTML ? What you want to do : select another option in your select, or only to change the first option text ?

Comment: Do you want to change value and/or value and text of option? Because, your current code changes attribute, if that's intention....

Comment: [check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/ayzvvzjq/)

Comment: Do you want this, actually? https://jsfiddle.net/e2jLnhb1/

Comment: @nevermind Yes! Hero! Thank you. I see I am getting confused between value and text attributes

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much on track here, however using `attr` isn't going to change the selected item for you as all you're doing is essentially changing the value of the returned `option` element from the jQuery selector from `"Search by Date"` to `"All Dates"`.

Within the `focus()` event listener, you can use `$("#select-dates").val()` to get the current value of the dropdown box. Then check this value against the value of the *first* `option` child element in the group.

If the current value matches the value of the first element, then use `$("#select-dates").val('all')` to assign the control's selected value to `all`.

**Demo**

You can see a jsFiddle I've prepared, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/brendonofficial/eyzbaua9/).

**HTML**

```
<select id="select-date">
  <option>- Select Date -</option>
  <option value="all">All Dates</option>
  <option value="2016-05">May, 2016</option>
  <option value="2016-04">April, 2016</option>
  <option value="2016-03">March, 2016</option>
  <option value="2016-02">February, 2016</option>
  <option value="2016-01">January, 2016</option>
  <option value="2015-12">etc, etc...</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("select#select-date").on('focus', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == $(this).find("option:first-child").val()) {
    $(this).val("all");
  }
});
```

This will work on any dropdown box where you'd like this sort of functionality to happen.